# Type definition with bar '|' operator

Tags: typescript

I came across a TypeScript code like below:

```
export type StatusCode =
    'A1' |
    'B2' |
    'C3'; 

let code: StatusCode = "C3";
```

What exactly the bar operator '|' does here? Do we have a similar feature in JavaScript?

While I can guess this should be something similar to `enum` I wanted to know the name of the topic, so I can search and learn it.

Comment: These look like Typescript union types. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe operator is used in TypeScript to either create **Union Types**, **Type Aliases** or, what you're actually looking for, **String Literal Types**. The latter is like a string Enum. You're basically determining which values a string can have.

[From the documentation:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

> String literal types allow you to specify the exact value a string
>   must have. In practice string literal types combine nicely with union
>   types, type guards, and type aliases. You can use these features
>   together to get enum-like behavior with strings.